# Differences beetween spectrum analysis in different software (Audacity, Cubase)

Tags: fft, audio, frequency-spectrum

I have group of `.wav` files that contains human speech (same person). Each file is 2-3 second long.

Now, I'm creating one long file (lets say `all.wav`) that contains all files mentioned above. Basically, all files are **concatenated** together, like this:

`|--file1--|--file2--|--file3--|...|--fileN--|`

There are about 100 files, so combined file has more or less 250 seconds.

Then, I'm creating another file (`masker-100000.wav`) which is 6 second long, and contains all files **mixed** together (100000 times) in random positions on 6 second axis in random order.

```
|0sec            6sec|
----------------------
|          --file56--|
|  --file3--         |
|ile99--             |
|       --file20--   |
|   --file56--       |
         ...
|                --fi|
```

The goal is to create speech-like noise (masker).

Both files are RMS normalized to same value (-27dBFS)

**The theory is, that these 2 files should have similar spectral density.** So I'm using [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) `Plot spectrum` tool to test it.

| `masker-100000.wav` | `all.wav` |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Masker spectral density plot] | [image: All spectral density plot] |

**And success!** Almost the same.
Lets now check with [`scipy`](https://scipy.org/)

```py
from scipy import signal
import soundfile as sf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

PATHS = ['./masker-100000.wav', './all.wav']

for path in PATHS:
    data, freq = sf.read(path)
    f, Pxx_den = signal.welch(data, freq, nperseg=1024, scaling='density')
    plt.semilogy(f, Pxx_den, label=path.split('/')[-1])

plt.legend(loc="lower left")
plt.xlabel("Frequency (Hz)")
plt.xscale('log')
plt.ylabel("Power Spectral Density (V^2/Hz)")
plt.show()
```

[image: Spectral density plot in Python]

Also looks good!

But then, when I'm using [Cubase](https://www.steinberg.net/cubase/) Spectrum Analyzer:

| `masker-100000.wav` | `all.wav` |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Masker spectral density plot in Cubase] | [image: All spectral density plot in Cubase] |

These two plots are clearly different. Especially after 2kHz.

Why such difference?
**It is very important for me**, to have 2 files with similar spectral density. And I don't know where is error

- Is Audacity wrong?
- Is Cubase wrong? Cubase seems more *professional* software.
- What algorithm does Cubase use? I can't find info on it.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt Steinberg would release internal functionality data of their products other than what's given in user documentation (maybe Steinberg's support forum or magazine  reviews are the places to hunt this data): https://steinberg.help/cubase_pro_artist/v9/en/cubase_nuendo/topics/audio_processing_and_functions/audio_processing_spectrum_analyzer_r.html   Have you configured all these analyzers equally?

Comment: I believe Juha P has a point here. You should have the same setup to get the same results. Please keep in mind that you use a spectral power density estimation method (Welch this is) in Python, which may have rather important differences to the algorithm provided in Cubase, which is kinda tailored for real-time mixing/mastering/production applications. I am not familiar with the algorithms behind Audacity's plot functions though. I do not suggest that this is the issue but I would start there. Since you got two similar results at the beginning I believe you should be good to go.

Comment: Cubase (or any software for that purpose) being more **professional** doesn't really mean much in the current context. Most probably, Cubase functions very well for its intended use, which may, or may not be the spectral estimation of audio files.

Comment: @JuhaP new versions of Cubase [does not have any configuration options for spectrum analyzer](https://steinberg.help/cubase_pro/v12/en/cubase_nuendo/topics/audio_functions/audio_functions_spectrum_analyzer_r.html). Anyway, im good with the results, but the only problem is that person who is responsible for "accepting" whole thing uses Cubase :). So I need strong evidence that spectral density for these files are similar, despite what Cubase shows. Do you know any other software for that kind of job? Yesterday I tried in Matlab, some results - similar densities.

Comment: @m51 this may seem a bit biased (it may or may not be, it's up to you to decide), but I believe that if you knew what you were doing with Matlab you should consider that the "reference". In my opinion, the same stands for your Python implementation but, at least Matlab, is considered to be robust and proven software package for this kind of calculations. This, of course, considering you know what you are doing.

Personally, if I were to vote, my vote would be with Matlab (as well as scipy and Audacity for that purpose).